# What's the best word to use for table overlapping the mobile screen to show the information on the right, "swipe left" or "slide left"?

Tags: mobile, tables, terminology, sliders, swipe

For me, the best way to show the list is by using cards either you scroll sideways or scrolling down by having each list stacked cards. With client preference to have the table similar UI and behavior to the desktop. What is the better term or word to use? Swipe left or Slide left?

From what I understand, Swipe (left) is changing a viewable element by replacing it with another similar UI element, and Slide (left) is to scroll horizontally a continuous element (ex table) within an area.

Answer (score 0):

These are two sides of one coin:

Swipe (left, right) is an action done by fingers.
Slide is to show a next, or a previous slide (part of some document or a data).

User does swipe to show some slide. User swipes left to show the left (previous) slide, right - the next slide (up, down the same).